# Datastore Location with Google App Engine / Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, maven-gae-plugin

How can I customize the location of the datastore file while working with GAE/J.

The option `--datastore_path` doesn't seem to work with GAE/J.

And if it is possible, what option do I use in the `maven-gae-plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean while running the dev app server locally. Try the `--generated_dir` option with `<sdk>/bin/dev_appserver.sh`:
 `--generated_dir=dir        Set the directory where generated files are created.`

The generated files include the local datastore file.

Comment: Great. works like a charm.

btw, can and how do I configure it using maven-gae-plugin

Comment: Never mind... noticed that it does not support it as of now. Submitted a patch myself :)